# How to get value of multiple data object in json with springmvc

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc

**customJquery.js**

```
var jsonURL=window.rootContext+'/get/all/information';

        $table.DataTable({
            lengthMenu: [[7,15,30,-1],['show 1 week','show 15 days','show 1 month','show All record']],
            pageLength:30,

            ajax:{
                url: jsonURL,
                dataSrc: ''
            },

            columns:[
                    {
                        data: 'id'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'day'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'month'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'year'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'eventName'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'eventDescription'
                    },
                {
                    data:'id',

                   mRender: function (data,type,row) {
                        var str='';
                        str+='<a href="'+window.rootContext+'/update/'+data+'/day/month/year">Update</a>'
                       return str;
                   }     
                }
                ]

        });
```

**AdminController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}/{day}/{month}/{year}")
public ModelAndView forwardUpdatePage(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("day") String day, @PathVariable("month") String month, @PathVariable("year") String year) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/index");
    modelAndView.addObject("id",id);
    modelAndView.addObject("day", day);
    modelAndView.addObject("month", month);
    modelAndView.addObject("year", year);
    modelAndView.addObject("title", "Update Event");
    modelAndView.addObject("userClickUpdateIcon", true);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

How to get value of id,day,month,eventName,and eventDescription from jsp file to `Controller` class using ajax.

I am trying to get all column value of datatable in controller class.I have no idea how to get all value using `@RequestParam` method in spring controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

Java script code :

```
            var first_name=$("#first_name").val().trim();
            var last_name=$("#last_name").val().trim();
            var phone_no=$("#phone_no").val().trim();
             $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'../signUp',
                        data:{firstName:first_name,lastName:last_name,phoneNo:phone_no},
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(response){
                            if(response=="SUCCESS"){
                               alert("Send Successfully.");
                            }else{
                                alert("Contact Admin");
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(){
                             console.log("Error in ajax of signUp");
                        }
                    });
```

Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.POST}, value={"/signUp"})
  @ResponseBody  public String signUp(SignUpPojo signupObj){
    String userInfo="User Details : "+ signupObj.toString();
    return "SUCCESS";
  }
```

Ensure to have the POJO with proper fields that you need.